# Return value from LinuxVM to Azure Pipeline

Tags: linux, azure, powershell, azure-devops, sh

The Linux VM is created using the Azure Pipeline. There is one folder which is created dynamically within the /data/config folder. The requirement is to return the name of this folder to the DevOps Pipeline.
The powershell code to invoke the shell script is as below

```
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -VMName $VirtualMachineName -CommandId RunShellScript -ScriptPath "$($PSScriptRoot)/scripts/$PatchScript"  -Parameter @{InputConf=$ReplInputConf}
```

I have done the following in the shell script and the folder name is written to a.txt

```
sudo -u $User find /data/config -maxdepth 1 -type d | sed 's/.*\///' >>  /log/a.txt
sudo -u $User sed -i "/^\s*$/d" /log/a.txt
```

How can I return the string in a.txt back to the pipeline?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You could try use a script to get the content of the txt file and set a variable `$var` for the content. Then use [Logging commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash) to set another variable in the variable service of taskcontext. This variable is exposed to the following tasks as an environment variable.

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]$var"
```